# How to auto add char at the head of line when hit enter in markdown file?

Tags: filetype-markdown

I write markdown in vim. When I write something in **list**.

The format will be

```
* item1
* item2
* item3
```

What I want is, when I finish `item1` then press <kbd>enter</kbd>. A `*` char can auto add to the head of next line. I think I may use a keymap make <kbd>enter</kbd> to a function which can do something basing on the context. But it seems too hard for me. Any easy way to do this?

Comment: Why not use one of the markdown plugins out there?

Comment: Yes I miss that thank you @gildux

Comment: You welcome @lizhe :) Maybe the default filetype-plugin can do it (it can do many things, but one has to enable some settings)